# Django - leaving url params the same after changing page

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have link looking like that:

```
<a class="page-link" href="{% url 'home-paginated' page_obj.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
```

and function getting params from current link:

```
function GetParams(){
   const queryString = window.location.search;
   console.log(queryString);
   return queryString
        }
```

and I'd like to set href value to connection of {% url 'home-paginated' page_obj.next_page_number %} and value returned by GetParams function (or just window.location.search)

for example
let current link be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/2?sorted=normal
```

and after clicking "a" tag link should look like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/3?sorted=normal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode the querystring again with `{{ request.GET.urlencode }}`:

```
<a class="page-link" href="{% url 'home-paginated' page_obj.next_page_number %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">Next</a>
```

Comment: I did as you said, but {{request.urlencode}} returns empy string i guess. When I click link i'm getting redirected to next page as before but there is additional "?" at the end of url

Comment: @KermitHQ: made a typo: is `request.GET.urlencode`.